# warnings can't find CharStreams after moving project

Tags: java, antlr4

I moved my `antlr4` based project which uses 6 different grammers to a different folder (and github depository). Now when I try to rebuild the Java project in I'm getting errors such as

```
Error:(30, 39) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable CharStreams
  location: class com.applitools.ekb.PhpExtractInterfaceTool
```

even though the code includes

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
```

and in a different grammar, it is even more explicit

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
```

In the latter case, InteliJ (2019) colors CharStreams in red and says `"cant resolve CharStreams"`

All I did is copy the project over and all works as expected in the original project. I tried to unistall and then reinstall the antlr4 plugin - didn't help.

Comment: What are you using as your build system for this project?

Comment: Show us where this dependency is defined (e.g. maven, gradle, etc.). If it is not defined anywhere, this is the problem; intellij is not magic. You need to tell it where the dependency is, either directly in your project structure, or indirectly via your build tool.

Comment: I can't see a pom file or gradle file in the source project - but it builds there.. I did a compare of the two tree structures and they are the same

Comment: The antlr4 library is defined in CLASS_PATH as described in the installation instruction - doesn't the compiler pick up the symbols from there?

Comment: main.iml file is ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/gen" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="org.antlr:antlr4-maven-plugin:4.5.2-1" level="project" />